# how to use multiple AdditionalFields in remote validation - asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, remote-validation

I need to validate the duplicate of FirstName, LastName and Email Address combination using remote validation in my ASP.NET MVC 4 (C#) application. The Remote Validation accepts only one AdditionalFields, which is as below:

```
 [Remote("IsUserNameAvailable", "User", AdditionalFields="LastName" )]
 public string FirstName{ get; set; }
 public string LastName{ get; set; }
 public string EmailAddress{ get; set; }
```

How can i add the EmailAddress for the combination?

Answer (score 54, accepted):

You could separate them by comma:

```
[Remote("IsUserNameAvailable", "User", AdditionalFields="LastName,EmailAddress" )]
```

Comment: N.B. If you want this to actually be revalidated when the additional fields change you will want to look at @Kiff's answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10163683/remote-validation-mvc-3-0-multiple-fields-validation